# jQuery is loading my root route and all the scripts again through XHR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I'm stuck with this problem for a few **days** and I think now is the time to get some help.

I'm updating my Angular app from v1.3.0-beta.17 to v.1.3.x (head) and now I'm getting this message `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`. The weird thing I noticed is that jQuery is loading the `/` route and all my scripts again afterwards through AJAX. See:

[image: Networks panel with the requests made by jquery]

Also this problem only occurs for one route (described below). Anyone would have any ideas on why jQuery is behaving like this?

Here's my routes:

`javascript
$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            'controller': 'loading',
            'templateUrl': versioning('/assets/template/system/blank.html')
        })
        .when('/dashboard/:dashboard_id', { // this is the route with error
            'controller': 'loading',
            'templateUrl': versioning('/assets/template/dashboard/dashboard.html')
        })
        .when('/dashboard/:dashboard_id/widget', {
            'controller': 'loading',
            'templateUrl': versioning('/assets/template/dashboard/widget.html')
        })
        .when('/dashboard/:dashboard_id/widget/:widget_id', {
            'controller': 'loading',
            'templateUrl': versioning('/assets/template/dashboard/widget.html')
        })
        //...
        .otherwise({
            'templateUrl': versioning('/assets/template/system/404.html')
        });`

Comment: This sounds like one of your templateUrl paths is not correct. I think when it can't find the file it reloads your index page or something and that's why you get the 'trying to load angular twice' spiel. Just double check all your url paths are actually pointing to the correct file and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually that you have a url pointing to a file that does not exist or it could be that you are missing the end of and html tag or something that causes your html to be invalid. Double check all your url paths and your html is correct.

Comment: You just guided me to the answer. The problem was a tab component inside the dashboard view that was probably generating invalid HTML. It worked as soon as I removed it.